Discrepancy Between Specific Record Query and Broader Query in Aurora MySQL
I'm experiencing an issue where a specific record appears in a detailed query [Query 1] but is missing in a broader query [Query 2] with similar conditions on an Amazon Aurora MySQL database. Here are the details:
Specific Query: [Query 1]
This query successfully retrieves the expected record: [The below query returns 1 row]
SELECT * 
FROM data_alerts.log_table 
WHERE incident_uuid = 63756315 
  AND run_status_flag = 'FAILED'
  AND job_name = 'lambda:LH_lambda'
  AND incident_category = 'LH'
  AND created_at_time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;

Broader Query: [Query 2]
However, when I run this broader query, the record is missing:
Please note that I removed the condition incident_uuid = 63756315. I expect the record returned by Query 1 to exist in the results of Query 2, but it is missing.
SELECT distinct job_details 
FROM data_alerts.log_table 
WHERE incident_category = 'LH'
  AND run_status_flag = 'FAILED'
  AND created_at_time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND job_name = 'lambda:LH_lambda'
ORDER BY created_at_time;

I also tried this query without the DISTINCT
clause, but the specific record still does not appear in the results. Here's the adjusted broader query:
SELECT job_details
FROM data_alerts.log_table 
WHERE incident_category = 'LH'
  AND run_status_flag = 'FAILED'
  AND created_at_time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND job_name = 'lambda:LH_lambda'
ORDER BY created_at_time;

Does anyone have any idea, why the record gets dropped in the results of second query

How many rows the 2nd query returns?   Is it the only "missing" row in the results of "broader/2nd" query?   Is ii anything special about this record as far as the fields you filter on are concerned?

@PM77-1  The second query returns multiple rows, but several records, including the specific one mentioned, are missing. The case I provided is with respect to one particular record, but this issue is not isolated to just this record. Multiple rows are missing from the results of the broader query.

are you running these from the same client code?  CURDATE is the current date in the connection's timezone (and IMO should always be avoided; use DATE(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) or DATE(CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'+00:00',some specific timezone))) and the two could differ.  note that some client libraries will "helpfully" set the connection timezone for you, rather than leaving it at the server's default

not related to your problem, but select distinct job_details...order by created_at_time is unlikely to do whatever it is you want; if you want it sorted by the earliest time a given job_details appears, do select job_details...group by job_details order by min(created_at_time).  if by the latest time, use max.
